# jhipster how to specify angular/cli version when generate client only

Tags: angular, jhipster

When I use below command to generate client only project using angular 4:

jhipster --skip-server --db mysql --auth jwt

all work except in generated package.json file: 
the @angular/cli version is 1.4.2
and the @angular/common version is 4.3.2

However when I use angular cli to generate angular project, the cli version is
1.5.0 and other angular module version is 5.0.0

My question is: 
How to use latest version of angular module and angular cli, or specify different version of such modules when use jhipster?

Note:

My global angular cli version is:1.5.0
my jhipster version is: 4.11.1
nodejs version is 6.11.3
windows version is: Windows 10, 64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't choose a specific version of Angular, when using JHipster. You need to modify yourself the version in package.json after generating.
But I'm not sure everything will work well but you can try.

The migration to Angular5 is coming. See https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/6789

A lot of work has been done for that. It's not just changing the version in package.json